# C++/CLI destructor

Tags: c#, c++-cli, destructor

I have a mixed language (C#, C++/CLI, native C++) application and I'm tracing the lifetime of some of the objects by putting log statements in constructors and destructors of several objects.  I have a C# object that contains a reference to a C++/CLI object.

```
public class MyC#Class
{
    public MyC#Class() { log.Debug("created MyC#Class object " + this.GetHashCode()); }
    ~MyC#Class() { log.Debug("destroyed MyC#Class object " + this.GetHashCode()); }
    private MyC++Class myC++Obj = new MyC++Class();
}
MyC++Class::MyC++Class() { loggerInt1(LOGDEBUG, "created MyC++Class object %d", (int)this->GetHashCode());
MyC++Class::~MyC++Class() { loggerInt1(LOGDEBUG, "destroyed MyC++Class object %d", (int)this->GetHashCode());
```

The problem is when the C# object is garbage collected I see the log statement from the C# destructor but I don't see the log statement from the C++/CLI object.  In other words I see the "destroyed MyC#Class object XXXX" but I don't see the corresponding "destroyed MyC++Class object YYYY".

As I understand it for both C# and C++/CLI the destructors override the Finalize() method that GC would normally call, so the MyC++Class destructor log statement would be printed when the MyC++Class object is garbage collected.

Other than the MyC++Class object is being referenced by something else and thus not yet time for GC, does annyone know of any reason why the MyC++Class destructor log statement is not being printed??

Thanks,

Comment: The mapping is different. Your ~MyClass is the Dispose method in C#. The missing !MyClass is the destructor in C#. Called the finalizer in any other language and in .NET literature. You don't see ~MyClass called because nobody disposed the object. You don't see !MyClass called because you didn't write it.

Comment: putting illegal class names in your code doesn't the question better.  Try `CppClass` and `CsClass` instead of `C++` and `C#`.

Answer (score 14):

A C++/CLI destructor is not the same as a C# finaizlier/destructor.  A C++/CLR descructor does not override the Finalize() and is not called during garbage collection.  C++/CLR has a different syntax to declare a finalizer which would be `MyC++Class::!MyC++Class` in your case.

A C++/CLI destructor is the equivalent of implementing `IDisposable` in C# and in fact does implement `IDisposable`.   To call the C++/CLI destructor from C# code you need to call the `Dispose()` method.  This is called out explicitly in the [C++/CLR documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177197%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I changed MyC++Class::~MyC++Class() to MyC++Class::!MyC++Class() but still the log statement in the finalizer is not printed.